# Xcode UITest find out if specific image exists inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimage, xcode-ui-testing

I have a `UITableView`, and in each cell there's a `UIImageView`, and each `UIImageView` contains a different image. Let's say one of the images is named 'SelectedImage'. How can I find out if 'SelectedImage' exists in the table?

I tried `app.images["SelectedImage"]`, `app.tables.images["SelectedImage"]`and they failed to find the element. I also tried to click on the image while recording the UI test, but the action comes up as if I clicked on the text beside it in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the XCUIElement tree by  app.debugDescription on your current UI

As per my understanding according to your descripton if i not wrong you have to mension table cell in you calling .
 You can see the below link

https://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/testing/user-interface-testing-swift-and-xctest